# DRF - 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got a front-end that sends JSON to the back-end to switch the input of a digital audio stream, with an optional time component to schedule the switch for the future. Here are the components of making this work:

from `views.py`:

```
class SwitchStreamView(views.APIView):
    """
    A custom endpoint for switching inputs of radio streams
    """
    queryset = RadioStream.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = serializers.RadioSwitchSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid()
        for stream in serializer.data:
            if stream.schedule_time is None:
                tasks.switch_stream(stream.mnemonic, stream.current_input)
            else:
                tasks.schedule_switch(stream.mnemonic, stream.current_input, stream.schedule_time)
        return HttpResponse('')
```

from `serializers.py`:

```
class RadioSwitchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    schedule_time = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_schedule_time(self, obj):
        return obj.get('schedule_time', None)

    class Meta:
        model = RadioStream
        fields = ('mnemonic', 'current_input', 'schedule_time')
```

The issue I'm having is that however I try and send a test JSON snippet, I'm getting errors. With this setup, sending

```
[
    {
        "mnemonic": "TEST",
        "current_input": "TEST"
    }
]
```

results in the error `'str' object has no attribute 'pk'`, but if I change `RadioSwitchSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)` to `many=False`, and send

```
{
    "mnemonic": "TEST",
    "current_input": "TEST"
}
```

I get the response `'str' object has no attribute 'schedule_time'` instead.

My plan was to use `mnemonic` to identify the stream, and `current_input` to identify which input to switch it to. My questions are; Why is this not working, and should I be using a non-Model serializer for this custom action instead of trying to fit the action into the existing fields of the model?

Edit: Here is the traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /api/switch/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "...\radio_switching\views.py", line 45, in post
    for stream in serializer.data:
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 738, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 266, in data
    self._data = self.get_initial()
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 573, in get_initial
    return self.to_representation(self.initial_data)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 656, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 656, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 500, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\relations.py", line 259, in to_representation
    return value.pk
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues, but it turns out the root issue was that `serlializer.data` was for whatever reason returning a string and not an array of objects. I ended up replacing the `ModelSerializer` with a regular `Serializer` here:

```
class RadioSwitchSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    mnemonic = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
    new_input = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
    schedule_time = serializers.DateTimeField(allow_null=True)
```

As per Jerin's answer, I also fixed up the lines accessing the `stream` dictionary to use square brackets rather than the dot operator. These two things have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `views.py` by this snippet,

```
class SwitchStreamView(views.APIView):
    """
    A custom endpoint for switching inputs of radio streams
    """
    queryset = RadioStream.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = serializers.RadioSwitchSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid()
        for stream in serializer.data:
            if 'schedule_time' not in stream:
                tasks.switch_stream(stream['mnemonic'], stream['current_input'])
            else:
                tasks.schedule_switch(stream['mnemonic'], stream['current_input'], stream['schedule_time'])
        return HttpResponse('')
```

The reason for the error is, you are trying to access a `python dict` using `dot operator`. To access dictionary elements, you can use the familiar square brackets along with the key to obtaining it's value. Here is the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

**EDIT**
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'` this error because, somewhere you trying to access `.pk` from a `str` object
**Reproducing the error**

```
In [7]: my_str = 'this is just a string'

In [8]: my_str.pk
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-5bc39c990550> in <module>()
----> 1 my_str.pk

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Comment: You may be right about this code, but after making this change I'm still receiving the `'str' object has no attribute 'pk'` error, so it's not the cause of the main error here. That said, if I try the `many=False` version, I'm now getting `string indices must be integers` instead of `'str' object has no attribute 'schedule_time'`

Comment: add your traceback in question section

Comment: I think `line Number 45 in /radio_switching/views.py` causing the exception. Can you add those related lines too?

Comment: That line is `for stream in serializer.data:` which gives me a better idea of what is going wrong now. I guess `serializer.data` isn't returning an array, but a string, and the iterator is having trouble iterating over it. I will investigate further.